# javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: FS_Proceduer already connected from /127.0.0.1:port

Tags: activemq-classic

How do you resolve this JMSException? Thanks!

Broker: localhost - Client: FS_Proceduer already connected

```
javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: FS_Proceduer already connected from /127.0.0.1:56556
```

This is triggered by this method:

```
private void connectAndInitActiveMQ() throws JMSException{
        logger.debug("It's ready to connect to jms service");
        if(null != connection){
            try{
                logger.debug("Closing connection");
                connection.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        logger.debug("Creating a new connection");

        logger.debug("Is queueConnectionFactory null? "+(queueConnectionFactory==null));

        connection = queueConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        logger.debug("Is the new connection null? "+(connection==null));

        logger.debug("Starting the new connection");
        connection.start();

        logger.debug("Connected successfully: " + connection);

        session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
    }
```

Is it the factory problem? Or some other source?

Comment: what are you trying to run? what exactly are the steps you performed and got stuck at this error? unless you include those it will be difficult to answer this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would get this error if you configured your connections to have the same client ID.  The JMS spec is explicit that only a single connection can connect to the remote with the same Client ID at any given time, resolve your configuration and things should work just fine.

Comment: Give each client connection its own client ID.

Comment: How may I disconnect or remove the same client ID ?